# Tracking paid ad clicks with Wordpress and Contact Form 7

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, forms, contact-form-7

A client wants to track contact form submissions that occur when a user enters the site by clicking Bing and Google paid ads. Their website uses WordPress and the information request form uses the Contact Form 7 plug-in.

He has several paid ads on both Google and Bing, and wants the contact form submission to include certain data indicating their IP address, what search engine they came from, and what ad they clicked.

How I currently have this set up is like this:

1. Bing/Google ads have their destination set to a PHP file on the client's website that sets session variables based on GET variables. For example:

   http://www.website.com/ads.php?src=Bing&cmp=CampaignName&paidClick=Y
2. This script sets the appropriate session variables and redirects the user to the appropriate product page with the information request form.
3. In the footer of the WordPress theme, there's some jQuery going on:

   ```
   var data = '<input type="hidden" name="src" id="src" value="<?php echo $_SESSION[\'src\'] ?>" />
   <input type="hidden" name="ip" id="ip" value="<?php echo $_SERVER[\'REMOTE_ADDR\'] ?>" />
   <input type="hidden" name="cmp" id="cmp" value="<?php echo $_SESSION[\'cmp\'] ?>" />
   <input type="hidden" name="paid" id="paid" value="<?php echo $_SESSION[\'paid\'] ?>" />';
   $(".wpcf7-form").append(data);
   ```
4. Then, in the Mail function of Contact Form 7 are the corresponding shortcodes such as [cmp] and [src].

My test shows that it is working; I clicked an ad on Bing and then submitted the form and it worked fine. The client reports that the data is missing though, and says my code doesn't work.  My test shows otherwise, but the client is always right.

So my question is this: Is there a better way to get "did they click a paid ad, and if so, which one" into a Contact Form 7 submission?